# for loop statement error

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, iteration

I want j `+100` in every iteration.But I don't know whats wrong with it .It is supposed to be okay .

```
for (int j=0;j<800;j+100){

body .
 }
```

> Error : not a statement

Comment: You want `j += 100`.

Comment: `j = j+100` or `j+=100`

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi Just a typo on my end. :) I fixed it

Comment: @yshavit good ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `j+=100` `to incremental your index with 100 :

```
for (int j=0; j<800; j+=100){
   //body
}
```

**Edit**

> any other methods to express +100

Here is another way:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 800; ) {
//----------------------^no parameter here
    //body
    j += 100;//this equivalent to j = j + 100;
}
```

Comment: any other expressions to express `+100`

Comment: check my edit @evalwt you can use it `+100` in your code also

Comment: @evalwt there are infinitely many ways to express it, e.g. `j /= 100, j++, j *= 100`, `j += 50, j += 50`, `j += 99, j -= 99, j += 100` etc. There's just none as concise as `j += 100`.

Comment: i agree yes this is totally correct @AndyTurner there are many ways